# accessing Request Object in Spring MessageConverters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request, converters

I am using Spring MessageConverter to encrypt/decrypt incoming/outgoing messages before request moves to actual REST API. However, I need to to do this based on what REST API method is called.

1) Can we access the request object somehow in the MessageConverters so that I can by-pass some code in the readFromSource() and writeToResult() methods?

2) Or will it be possible to call a  new MessageConverter based on request attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to modify the supplied HttpMessageConverters to modify the request or response. You can make use of a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor with RestTemplate.

This can intercept the request before it is dispatched to the REST API. For example

```
public class EncryptingClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor{

  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException{
body[] encrypted = encrypt(body); //encrypt method define the encryption logic
return execution.execute(request, encrypted);
}
```

Then register your interceptor with the RestTemplate

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
   RestTemplate instance = new RestTemplate();
   instance.getInterceptors().add(new EncryptingClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
}
```

On the server side you can use the HandlerInterceptor strategy to decrypt the request before it reaches the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter and encrypt befor the response is sent out

Comment: Dear Ekem chitsiga,           Thanks for your reply.   Do we have ResponseInterceptor same way in Spring MVC as well. I need that also. plz help.